# java and interfaces implementing different parameter types

Tags: java, interface

I'm working on a basic math interface and wondering if there's a way I can specify that the type parameter can only be an integer or float without using the  type?

for example, this is the basic layout, where  is is where I'm trying to say Integer or Float without hard coding it into the actual abstract method.

```java
public interface Math<T> {

    T add(T t, T r);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please read: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: didnt have any errors was just sort of discussing the topic of possibilities or not

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to restrict the type of a generic to a specific few but you could just require a float since floats will behave like integers

Comment: ah very true, did not think of it like that, i guess the only other way would be to make specific interfaces accepting either Integer or Float

Comment: That would work too. I think the easiest thing to do here is to just accept the generic and then check the type at the start of the method since you only have two cases to check.

Comment: "*... since floats will behave like integers*" - No, they don't. They are floating point precision values. Please be careful with statements like this.

Answer (score 0):

Using `<T extends Number>` can restrict this to Number or its subclasses. You can check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html